# Is there an official documentation for how to request camera access in Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, camera, mobile-safari

Working on a QR code scanner app that runs in the browser. I searched for an hour but couldn't find any official documentation from Apple targeting mobile Safari and how to go about requesting camera access in JavaScript correctly. I ended up finding [official documentation for "Safari"](https://developer.apple.com/safari/), which covers the Desktop Safari only.

Are there any official resources in this matter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MediaDevices-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) like this:

```
async function getMedia(constraints) {
  let stream = null;

  try {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    /* use the stream */
  } catch(err) {
    /* handle the error */
  }
}
```

MDN states that the API is usable in mobile safari from version 11

Comment: Thank you. So you are not aware of any official docs from Apple regarding Mobile Safari specifically?